# wc_get_products returns empty array?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have made a plugin so I can have custom endpoints. Ultimately I want to pull data about my bookable products (woocommerce bookings).

Here is my plugin:

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins',
        get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

    // Define constants.
    define( 'CUSTOM_ENDPOINTS_PLUGIN_VERSION', '1.0.0' );
    define( 'CUSTOM_ENDPOINTS_PLUGIN_DIR', __FILE__  );


    // Include the main class.
    require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/class-rest-custom-woocommerce-endpoints.php';

}
```

Then in my main class file:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', 'get_data');
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'custom_endpoint_first');


           function custom_endpoint_first(){
            register_rest_route( 'cwe/v1/booking', '/get-data',
                                array(
                                'methods' => 'GET',
                                'callback' => 'get_data')
             );
           }

           function get_data() {

               $args = array( 'include' => array(28));

               $products = wc_get_products( $args );



               return $products;
           }
```

I don't know why it returns an empty array but it has 200 status when I call my custom URL.

Answer (score 7):

Use this snippet to get products in JSON.

```
public function get_products()
{
    $p = wc_get_products(array('status' => 'publish'));
    $products = array();
    foreach ($p as $product) {
        $products[] = $product->get_data();
    }
    return new WP_REST_Response($products, 200);
}
```

Comment: Great. But don't know why WP_REST_Response is not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This line

`'include' => array(28)`

means that you will only get a product with id 28.
Does that product exist?
Is that your intention? 
 
If not, check out this link for some examples
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query#usage

Comment: Hey! Yeah this product exist ideally I would like to just pull all my products but I just did it to test as the former was still giving me an empty array as well.